# Two-way sensitivity graph using Stata

Tags: graph, stata

I am evaluating a healthcare decision model and would like to display the results of a two-way sensitivity analysis. I have included the code for creating the ranges for the two variables of interest and their linear predictors (days of life).

Instead of points, I would like to have the red and blue areas shaded. I attempted `rarea` and `area` commands in `twoway`, but this does not achieve the desired effect. The scatter plot coded below is the best approximation of the final result I could achieve.

```
*create all possible pairs of data
clear
set obs 40

gen a = 0.20 if [_n] == 1
    replace a = a[_n-1] - 0.02 if [_n] != 1

gen b = a

fillin a b

*predict estimates from equation
gen pred = a*-1067.54 + b*-89.1

*identify all estimates >= 90 days
gen _90 = pred >= 90

*plot predictions by status of exceeding 89 days
twoway scatter a b if _90 == 1 || scatter a b if _90 == 0
```

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are trying to do `twoway contour` should work

```
clear
set obs 40
gen a = 0.20 if [_n] == 1
replace a = a[_n-1] - 0.02 if [_n] != 1
gen b = a
fillin a b
gen pred = a*-1067.54 + b*-89.1
gen _90 = pred >= 90

twoway (contour _90 a b, levels(2) scolor(mint) ecolor(magenta) heatmap)
```

Of course you can try playing with the additional options for `contour` (`help twoway_contour`) and additional twoway plot options (`help twoway_options`).

For example:

```
twoway (contour _90 a b, scolor(mint) ecolor(magenta) levels(2) heatmap ///
    zlabel(.25 "0" .75 "1"))
```

adding `zlabel()` to re-define the values used on the legend. Additional options are available to change the position of the legend and so on. Also note that, because `contour` is a twoway plot type, it can be conbined with other twoway plots as well.